# Changing tab length in Canopy's editor

Tags: enthought, canopy, epd-python

Sorry if this is not an appropriate question, but when I emailed Enthought they referred me to here to ask the question.

Is there a way to change the default number of spaces that a tab creates (for indentation purposes) in Enthought's Canopy python editor? I would like it to indent by 2 spaces instead of the 4 spaces it currently inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not AFAIK. The editor is python-centric, tries to avoid option-overload, and respects http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation